# Regex to match YouTube links, need to omit end of line from match

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

(Simplified) code from a WordPress project:

```
function fix_youtube_links ($content) {
    $append = '&w=480&rel=0';
    $content = preg_replace('/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/(?:v\/|watch[\/\#?])|(youtu\.be\/)).*/im', '$0'.$append, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'fix_youtube_links');
```

`$content` looks something like this:

```
blah blah blah

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUtdP3jQKUA

blah blah blah
```

And I want to add `$append` to the matches and get this:

```
blah blah blah

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUtdP3jQKUA&w=480&rel=0

blah blah blah
```

But instead I am getting this:

```
blah blah blah

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUtdP3jQKUA
&w=480&rel=0

blah blah blah
```

...because the end-of-line is being included in the match.

Any suggestions? Regex or non-regex solutions welcomed.

Comment: FYI: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rUtdP3jQKUA` is only one way to link to Youtube videos. There are many more. The video you linked could also be reached via `http://youtu.be/rUtdP3jQKUA` for example.

Comment: Or `http://www.youtube.com/e/rUtdP3jQKUA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$content = preg_replace('/^http:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube.com\/(?:v\/|watch[\/\#?])|(youtu\.be\/))[^\n\r]*/im', '$0'.$append, $content);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! @meagar, thanks for the additional tips.